# How do you drop all tables from an app in Django 1.8+?

Tags: django, django-admin, django-1.8

I am upgrading Django 1.4 to 1.8, and there are some 3rd party applications whose schema changed dramatically to support the upgrade. I want to reset these applications so I can recreate the corresponding tables from them. In the previous Django iterations, I can do either

```
./manage.py sqlclear appname
```

or

```
./manage.py reset appname
```

But both sqlclear and reset are already deprecated in Django 1.8. Is there a clean way to do this aside from manually erasing the tables from the database?

Comment: have you tried `migrate appname zero`?

Comment: @schowbaseggl Yup, doesn't erase the tables.

Comment: @Irvan it deletes the tables, tested on Django 2.1

Answer (score 3):

As of Django 1.8+ migrate appname **zero** unapplies all the migrations and deletes the tables [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/django-admin/#migrate)

Answer (score -2):

Take a look at Django Extensions, which give a slew of useful commands, including:

```
manage.py reset_db
```

https://github.com/django-extensions/django-extensions

Good luck!

Answer (score -4):

Drop your Database and create it again its the fastest way !

Comment: I think when your migrations are huge, that's not the fastest way

Comment: This destroys your database. Most people upgrading across such a large version set have quite a bit of data they don't want to lose...